# Jira Script Console with Jython

Tags: jira, jython

I'm new to the Jira Script Console.  I would have thought that:

```
def test():
   print 'this is a test'
   return 'testing'

test()
```

would do the obvious, but I'm getting a return value of 'no return value' and either the print statement isn't working or I'm looking for it in the wrong place (the Chrome console).

Anything?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this works as expected, when using `print` the output is redirected to the server log which is `catalina.out`. On my Linux server, the file is at:

```
/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out
```

When running the script above the string `this is a test` will be appended to the file.